# Possible diet for a week

Tags: scripture, food

While listening Lalitha Sahastranaama, I came to know about the mention of a 9 month diet for a pregnant women. It may be for the well being of both mother and offspring.

As we know that there are four varnas and many scriptures recommend food *items* based on the varna.

I am searching for mention of complete diet for any varna. Is there any mention of such diet in any of the scripture instead of just recommendation of items?